# Как вставить php в Custom field wordpresss?

Tags: php, wordpress, парсер

Как в произвольное поле вставить php код и потом его вывести на этой же странице (записи)? есть запись = карточка товара, где цена на этот товар парсится с другого сайта (меняется почти каждый день). Делать это в кастом филдс хочу, потому что потом нужно будет фильтровать все записи (товары) по цене.

```
$page = file_get_contents('URL');
preg_match_all('/<td.*?>(.*?)<\/[\s]*td>/is', $page, $matches); 
foreach ($matches as $val) { 
for ($i=19; $i <= 26; $i++){ 
echo $val[$i]; } }
```

Comment: Никак. В произвольное поле вставить php код нельзя.

Comment: Что мешает вставлять/обновлять сразу значения?

Comment: @SeVlad количество записей 1000, цена меняется несколько раз в день. Вставлять/обновлять сразу значения мешает здравый смысл.

Comment: Вы избрали неверный путь решения задачи. Покажите ваш код.

Comment: Да хоть миллион! Я разве говорил о ручной правке?. Ессно автоматизировано всё должно быть.

Comment: @KAGGDesign $page = file_get_contents('URL');
 
preg_match_all('/<td.*?>(.*?)<\/[\s]*td>/is', $page, $matches);
 
foreach ($matches as $val) {
    
    for ($i=19; $i <= 26; $i++){ 
      echo $val[$i+];
    }
    
}

Comment: Под вопросом есть кнопка "править". Используйте её для добавления кода в вопрос, там он будет читаемым.